# Rails dynamic collection_select only filters about 50% of the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've implemented a dynamic selection, where users will choose the project they are working on in one selection and then a dropdown with several "subtasks" will appear.
This works but only about 50% of the time, sometimes the second dropdown contains all projects with their subtasks, other times the subtasks will populate based on on the project selected.

This is my Task.js function:

```
    function showForm() {
      const btn = document.getElementById('new-task-form')
      btn.style.display == "block" ? btn.style.display = "none" : btn.style.display = "block"
    }

    jQuery(function() {
      let subtasks;
      subtasks = $('#task_subproject_id').html();
      return $('#task_project_id').change(function(){
        let project, optons;
        project = $('#task_project_id :selected').text();
        options = $(subtasks).filter("optgroup[label='" + project + "']").html();
        if(options) {
          return $('#task_subproject_id').html(options);
        } else {
          return $('#task_subproject_id').empty();
        }
      });
    });
```

This is the new partial where the collections are displayed:

```
    <%= form_for(@task, method: :post, remote: true, html: {class: "form-group"}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label "Describe the task"%>
      <%= f.text_field :comments, id: "task-comments", class: "form-control" %>
      <br />
      <%= f.label "Time in minutes" %>
      <%= f.text_field :time, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= f.label "Project" %>
      <%= f.collection_select :project_id, Project.order(:name), :id, :name,
          {prompt: "Select a project"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
      <br />
      <%= f.grouped_collection_select(:subproject_id, Project.order(:name), :subprojects, :name,
          :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a subtask" },{class: "form-control"}) %>
    <br / />
      <%= f.label "Date" %>
      <%= f.date_select :day,  {class: "form-control"}%>

      <br  />
      <%= f.label "Collaborators" %>
      <ul class="list-group collaborators">
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.where.not(id: current_user.id), :id, :email_or_user_name) do |box| %>
        <li class="list-group-item"> <%= box.check_box + box.text%> </li>

        <% end %>
        </ul>
      <%= f.submit "Add Task", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
```

Again this works about 50% of the time.  I've tried it in multiple browsers; Safari, Chrome, IE, Opera does not seem to be a browser issue, and when it dosen't work there is not console error.

Comment: When it not works if you reload a page will it start to work? Do you use turbolinks in the project?

Comment: Generally I have found that reloading the page works.  Yes I use turbolinks.

Comment: Try to replace `$(document).on('ready', function() { })` with `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { })` in js files

Comment: Seems to work!  Thank you.